# SQL: group dates into specific weekly intervals

Tags: mysql, sql

SQL newbie here. I'm looking at a query that has sales data split by day. Is it possible to group individual days into continuous 3-day intervals? E.g., how do I turn table A into table B?

Table A:

| Date | Sales |
| --- | --- |
| 07/11/2021 | 100 |
| 08/11/2021 | 100 |
| 09/11/2021 | 100 |
| 10/11/2021 | 200 |
| 11/11/2021 | 200 |
| 12/11/2021 | 200 |

Table B:

| Date | Sales |
| --- | --- |
| 07/11/2021 - 09/11/2021 | 300 |
| 10/11/2021 - 12/11/2021 | 600 |

Comment: Use `GROUP BY FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date) / (86400 * 3))`

Comment: Thanks @Barmar. For my understanding, what does '86400' refer to?

Comment: The number of seconds in a day.

Comment: @Barmar I'm on the BigQuery Query Editor page via Google Sheets & it states that the function UNIX_TIMESTAMP cannot be found. Is there an alternative I can use?

Comment: You have the `mysql` tag, so I used a MySQL function.